# How can I use Google Analytics to determine how popular a feature is on my site?

Tags: google-analytics

I have a forum on my site and I want to get a sense of how popular it is with my users.

The forum is made up of pages at 4-5 different URLs, i.e. /forum, /readThread, /postToForum, etc...

I think the most useful stats to get would be what % of sessions used this feature (= touched one or more of the URLs that make up the feature) and what % of unique visitors used this feature. (I don’t think it would be useful at all to get pageviews. I just want a general sense of how many are using the form in any capacity.)

How can I easily get this data?

If that's too hard, then I can narrow it down to one URL, and I'd just be looking for the same two stats.

Thanks.

Comment: It seems like you could just look at (forum pageviews / total pageviews), no? There's got to be a way to aggregate all those URLs to get a total that you can divide.

Comment: Hmmm but if a small % of my members use the forums but rack up a ton of pageviews in there, it's going to skew the results.

Comment: I meant to say uniques, not views, but I'm glad you figured it out using a segment!

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating a segment (in settings) with custom parameters:

**Sessions must include the pages with URLs that contain [the URLs I want]**

Then I can just graph all sessions against sessions in this segment and figure out the percentage.